# What is the correct syntax for SELECT statement and WHERE clause?

Tags: android, sqlite, select

I am trying to explore android and I just started using SQLite database. I'm wondering on what is the right syntax for selecting a single row from a table, where the row I want to select is from the value entered from a user using `editText`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: our friend google helped me find you this:  http://sqlite.awardspace.info/syntax/sqlitepg03.htm

Comment: also try this http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to disagree with both of the answers above.  What if the user enters this query:

```
Bobby Tables'; drop table yourTable;
```

See: http://xkcd.com/327/

I believe you should do this instead:

```
String query = "select * from TABLE_NAME WHERE column_name=?";
String[] selection = new String[1];
selection[0] = users_entered_value;
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, selection);
```

ETA: Actually, the more I think about it, the more I think you're going in the wrong direction.  If your app depends on a database query returning exactly one unique match to an arbitrary string entered by the user, it's probably going to be broken a great deal of the time.

What you should probably do is something like this:

```
String query = "select * from TABLE_NAME WHERE column_name LIKE ?";
String[] selection = new String[1];
selection[0] = "%" + users_entered_value + "%";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, selection);
```

and then iterate through the results and pick a "best" match according to your own criteria.

Also, you should create the table with case-insensitive matching for the column(s) you're going to be searching.

Answer (score 0):

SQLiteDatabase db;

db.rawQuery("select * from yourTable where your_column_name = 'users_entered_value' limit 1", null);

Comment: Where can i declare this query?

Comment: Sorry I don't follow but what do you mean by declaring the query?

Comment: String query = "select * from yourTable where your_column_name = 'users_entered_value' limit 1";

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLiteDatabase db; 

// make connection to your database ;

Cursor c = null ;

String SQL = "select * from TABLE_NAME where column_name='VALUE'";

c = db.rawQuery(SQL);
```

**c contains your result array of query you fired.**

You can retrieve values using loop.